# Invalid value for option "output.dir" when setting "rollupOptions.output.file"

Tags: vite, rollup

I'm trying to set up my vite build so that it outputs one js file, with a pre-defined name. Here is my `vite.config.js`:

```
build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/scripts/foo.ts"),
      name: "foo",
      formats: ["es"],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        file: "foo",
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        format: "es",
      },
    },
  }
```

This config results in an error message: `Invalid value for option "output.dir" - you must set either "output.file" for a single-file build or "output.dir" when generating multiple chunks.`

But if I set the `rollupOptions.output.dir` option - a single JS file is created (so no multiple chunks).

I want to generate a single js file in my `dist` folder, that has all dependencies bundled into it, with a pre-defined name. Is there any configuration that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this config instead:

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/scripts/foo.ts"),
      fileName: 'foo',
      formats: ['es']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        dir: 'dist',
      },
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).